# css last child in breadcrumb template

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs

I have done a breadcrumb template by using CSS. But the problem is, I am not able to remove the arrow (It should be simple without an arrow) from the last child.

I also need plain active css only for the last child.

Here is my demo
http://jsfiddle.net/gDAq4/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the pseudo-elements on only the last `li`:

```css
#vert_menu li:last-child a::after,
#vert_menu li:last-child a::before {
    content: none;
}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/gDAq4/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
#vert_menu li:last-child a {  background:none; }
#vert_menu li:last-child a::after, #vert_menu li:last-child a::before {  border:none; }
```