# Modifying breadcrumb: How can I make the last element squared? (html, css)

Tags: html, css

```css
.breadcrumb {
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 14px) 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 14px) 100%, 0 100%);
}
.breadcrumb #last {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% + 15px) 88, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 14px) 100%, 0 100%);
}
.breadcrumb a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
  margin-right: -17px;
}
.breadcrumb a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
}
.breadcrumb a:first-child {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="breadcrumb">
  <a href="#">Hodddddddme</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="#">Some extra long name</a>
  <a href="#">Email</a>
  <a id="last" href="#4">Email</a>
</nav>
```

Right now, the breadcrumb ~in the jsfiddle~ is an arrowed shape at the right-end.

How can I make the last element squared just like the very first element of the breadcrumb?

Comment: Similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557153/css-last-child-in-breadcrumb-template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make some changes in your code -

1 - remove the `clip-path` property from `.breadcrumb` class

2- change the `clip-path` values from `.breadcrumb a#last` class

```css
.breadcrumb {
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  /*-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 14px) 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 14px) 100%, 0 100%);*/
}



.breadcrumb a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
  margin-right: -17px;
}
.breadcrumb a#last{
  -webkit-clip-path:polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 0px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 0px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
  clip-path:polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 0px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 0px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
}

.breadcrumb a:hover{
  background-color: blue;
}

/* Just to show that even around the arrow head, the mouse pointer is at the correct link */ 
a:hover {
  color: red;
}

/* first link should not have anything cliped on the left side */
.breadcrumb a:first-child {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="breadcrumb">
    <a href="#">Hodddddddme</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">Some extra long name</a>
    <a href="#">Email</a>
    <a id="last" href="#4">Email</a>
  </nav>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: All my pleasure :)

Comment: I am sorry but I have one more question. How can I make the element a solid rectangle when there is only one element? http://jsfiddle.net/pqmkf2qp/ right now there is a remaining arrow shape when it's solely used.

Comment: then you have to chnage `.breadcrumb a:first-child` class http://jsfiddle.net/pqmkf2qp/1/ (it will good if you make a new class for it)

Answer (score 1):

Try this but you also have to remember that if you want to make it adjustable for all viewports then you have to write `media-query`.

```css
.breadcrumb {
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 14px) 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 14px) 100%, 0 100%);
}

.breadcrumb #last{
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 0px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 0px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 0px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 0px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
}

.breadcrumb a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
  margin-right: -17px;
}

.breadcrumb a:hover{
  background-color: blue;
}

/* Just to show that even around the arrow head, the mouse pointer is at the correct link */ 
a:hover {
  color: red;
}

/* first link should not have anything cliped on the left side */
.breadcrumb a:first-child {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="breadcrumb">
  <a href="#">Hodddddddme</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="#">Some extra long name</a>
  <a href="#">Email</a>
  <a id="last" href="#4">Email</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: I think the last element should be squared in the opposite direction

Comment: ok I thought you were asking for the starting point let me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```css
ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;border-top-right-radius:4px; border-top-left-radius:4px
}
#vert_menu{overflow: hidden;  width: 100%; }
#vert_menu li{  float: left;}
#vert_menu a{
  padding: 8px 20px 8px 40px;
  float: left; text-align:center;
  text-decoration: none; font: normal 16px Myriad Pro, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #000;
  color: #e6e2cf;
  position: relative; text-shadow:1px 0 0 #000;
  background-color: #525252; min-width:60px; width:auto
}
#vert_menu a:last-child::after{
 background:none; 
}

#vert_menu a:first-child{
   border-top-left-radius:4px
}
#vert_menu li:first-child a{  padding-left: 1em; }
#vert_menu a:hover{  background: #afab9d;}
#vert_menu a::after,
#vert_menu a::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -19px;   
  border-top: 19px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 19px solid transparent;
  border-left: 1em solid;
  right: -1em;
}
#vert_menu a::after{   z-index: 2;  border-left-color: #525252;  }

#vert_menu a::before{
  border-left-color: #f8f5ee;  
  right: -1.1em;
  z-index: 1; 
}

#vert_menu a:hover::after{
  border-left-color: #afab9d;
}
#vert_menu .current,
#vert_menu .current:hover{
  background: #afab9d;
}
#vert_menu .current::after,
    #vert_menu .current::before{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      margin-top: -1.5em;   
      border-top: 1.5em solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 1.5em solid transparent;
      border-left: 1em solid;
      border-left-color: #afab9d;  
      right: -1em;
     }




#vert_menu li:last-child a::after,
#vert_menu li:last-child a::before{
    content: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="vert_menu">
        <li><a href="#">Hodddddddme</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">VContact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Some extra long name</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
        <li><a href="#4">Email</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution @user7677413

http://jsfiddle.net/o3nhzxg7/3/ updated fiddle link

```css
.breadcrumb {
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 14px) 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 14px) 100%, 0 100%);
}

.breadcrumb #last{
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% + 15px) 88, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 14px) 100%, 0 100%);

}

.breadcrumb a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
  margin-right: -17px;
}

.breadcrumb a:hover{
  background-color: blue;
}

/* Just to show that even around the arrow head, the mouse pointer is at the correct link */ 
a:hover {
  color: red;
}

/* first link should not have anything cliped on the left side */
.breadcrumb a:first-child {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%);
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.breadcrumb a:last-child {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 0%, calc(100% - 0px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 0%, calc(100% - 0px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
 
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="breadcrumb">
  <a href="#">Hodddddddme</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="#">Some extra long name</a>
  <a href="#">Email</a>
  <a id="last" href="#4">Email</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: @Hash i included your update fiddle link, check in that

Comment: @shah btw when i view it in full shows arrow still.

Comment: @Hash see the fiddle again it is perfect.